# Eliminating multiple Elseif statements

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, combobox

Im trying to keep my code clean and especially using Comboboxes in userforms there can be a lot of if Elseif statements. There should be an easier way to not have multiple pages of code for just one combobox is there?

Example of how it is done now:

```
Sub Example()
Dim Variable as String
If Combobox1.Value = "Option1" Then
        Variable = "Name1"
    Elseif Combobox1.Value = "Option2" Then
        Variable = "Name2"
    Elseif Combobox1.Value = "Option3" Then
        Variable = "Name3" 
    Elseif Combobox1.Value = "Option4" Then
        Variable = "Name4"
    Else Variable = "Name5"
End if
End Sub
```

As you can imagine this can become a LONG code for 20 names, imagine having 3-4 dropdown menu's. Is there any (acceptable/known) way of simplifying this?

Comment: Although I am sure your real-world usage is not as simple as above, if you just want a static value for each combo item, include the value in a hidden column in the combo box. Then you can just grab that column without any IF statements.  Another option is to use 'CASE', but that may look almost as cluttered.

Comment: The CASE option actually looks great, altough the code will not significantly decrease in terms of length it does clean it up, make it better readable. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim arr, res
    Dim Variable as String

    arr = Array(Array("Option1", "Name1"), _
                Array("Option2", "Name2"), _
                Array("Option3", "Name3"), _
                Array("Option4", "Name4"))

    res = Application.VLookup(Combobox1.Value, arr, 2, 0)
    If Not IsError(res) Then
        Variable = res
    Else
        Variable = "Name5"
    End If
End Sub
```